# axios response doesn't filled

Tags: reactjs, axios, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I'm making react app which search on Youtube and show some list of video by using create-react-app.
My problem is the document of response from axios.get() only contains scripts and empty skeleton tag.
I want this has some contents inside of it like when opened from browser. why this happen? and what should i study?

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  onSubmitFormSearch = async (text) => {
    console.log("axios", text);
    const response = await axios.get(`/results?search_query=${text}`, {
      responseType: "text",
      responseEncoding: "utf8",
    });

    console.log(response.data);
  };

  render() {
    return <SearchBar onSubmitForm={this.onSubmitFormSearch} />;
  }
}
export default App;
```

this is my react code

here's document of response  https://codepen.io/im0505/pen/MWaMKXa

Comment: you may add the responded html to the DOM and hope it renders. something into this direction, but don't know how (or if) this actually works.

Comment: thank you. can i see some example?

Comment: I have non. It's just an idea on how to solve your issue. But a better way would probably be to query for *information*, not the whole *page* ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the complete webpage just like you see in browser when visualising the response of `axios.get`. The fundamental reason is that when you load an URL in browser, browser executes the scripts from the response of the request which doesn't happen when visualising response of request made by axios.

What Happens When You Type in a URL : [Source](https://wsvincent.com/what-happens-when-url/)

1. You enter a URL into a web browser
2. The browser looks up the IP address for the domain name via DNS
3. The browser sends a HTTP request to the server
4. The server sends back a HTTP response
5. The browser begins rendering the HTML
6. The browser sends requests for additional objects embedded in HTML (images, css, JavaScript) and repeats steps 3-5.
7. Once the page is loaded, the browser sends further async requests as needed.

Points **6 and 7** doesn't happen when you are looking at the result in Codepen or in your axios response

Comment: thank you for answer. then how can i get the complete webpage in front-end?

Comment: @younghoPark What information do you need from the webpage? Can you get the required information from Youtube search API?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search

Comment: I want to get information without using API. that is the purpose